# Module not found: Error Can't resolve 'routes.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on incorporating a React theme into my existing project. Getting the following error message and not sure how to resolve it

```
ERROR in ./src/components/navbars/DemoNavBar.js 9:0-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'routes.js' in 'C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\src\components\navbars'     
resolve 'routes.js' in 'C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\src\components\navbars'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\package.json (relative path: ./src/components/navbars)   
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\src\components\navbars\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory      
      C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\src\components\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\pee
rplatform\peerplatform-fe\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/routes.js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration  
              C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\node_modules\routes.js.js doesn't exist
            .json
      ...
      C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Users\15512\Desktop\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\15512\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\15512\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/routes.js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration  
              C:\Users\15512\node_modules\routes.js doesn't exist
            .web.mjs
      ...   
        C:\Users\15512\node_modules\routes.js doesn't exist
      C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\pee
rplatform\peerplatform-fe\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/routes.js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration  
              C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\node_modules\routes.js doesn't exist
            .web.mjs
...
 @ ./src/layouts/Admin.js 9:0-61 63:38-48
 @ ./src/App.js 14:0-45
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 19:33-36
```

This is the structure of my project

```
--peerplatform-fe
----node_modules
----src
-------components
-------views
-------layouts
    routes.js
```

Here is my routes.js file

```
import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard.js";
import TableList from "./views/Tables.js";

var routes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "User Profile",
    // icon: "nc-icon nc-single-02",
    component: Dashboard,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/tables",
    name: "Table List",
    // icon: "nc-icon nc-tile-56",
    component: TableList,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
];
export default routes;
```

Comment: What happens when commenting ``component:`` key on routes array?

Comment: @MiloshN. I get the same error

Comment: I believe routes.js should be within src.

Comment: @unfestivechicken it is